# How to store load data infile details in a variable

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, unix

Below is my sample shell script code

```
result=$(mysql -u$user -p$rep_password -h$rep_host -D$db_name -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'/sample/table.txt' INTO TABLE $table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"';" )
echo $result
```

I want to store the below sample output details after this query execution, but I can't get anything, please help

```
Query OK, 5 rows affected, 20 warnings (0.00 sec)    
Records: 5  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you redirect the output to a file, then cat the file, i.e

```
mysql -u$user -p$rep_password -h$rep_host -D$db_name -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'/sample/table.txt' INTO TABLE $table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"';">/tmp/output
cat /tmp/output
```